# Why won't the pictures show on my website?

Tags: html, css, image, display

I'm new to coding. We got a school assignment to make our first website.
It's ONLY HTML and CSS. 'Munksgaard.one'.

On the site: "OM" I can't get my pictures to load.
The pictures are uploaded to one.com with the correct names and is reffered to correctly in the HTML document. I can see them when i open them from my browser. It is as soon as i upload them to one.com, they dissapear, but all my other content seems to work?

**HTML**

```
<center>
  <div style="width:830; background-color:white; height:120px">
    <img class="img" style=" display:inline" src="hjemmet.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="lys" />
    <img class="img" style=" display:inline"  src="hjemmeside.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="udkast" />
  </div>
</center>
```

**CSS**

```
.img {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: grey; 
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools and look in the console for errors.

Comment: The most likely reason is that the path to the images is incorrect or permissions on the server are not set correctly.

Comment: Do you provide the correct & _full_ path?

Comment: @Bobface yeah, i think so. It worked with the other images on the site?

Comment: @j08691 it's says "2 errors" - "404 not found"

Comment: I think before posting to SO you would be better off doing some reading and research into basic html, css and how web servers work. I appreciate your newbie status, but this is something that could be figured out by doing your due diligence with learning basic concepts.

Comment: Did you make sure that _hjemmet.jpg_ and _hjemmeside.jpg_ are in the same directory as the .html-file?

Comment: Welp, that tells me that the images aren't where you think they are. Either the path to them is incorrect, the file names are incorrect, or the permissions are incorrect.

Comment: @Munksgaard 404 error means the images could not be found. That means they are not in the same directory.

Comment: @HeadCode I know. I have only been coding for 2 days. So it's a little much.. This is the only error i can't get my head around. I have been researching for hours. And I still can't find the error!

Comment: I FOUND THE ANSWER! Thank you so much for the help. My PC had - for some reason - automatically changed .jpg to .JPG - that was the problem...

Comment: Hah congrats, had that problem once before. Damn you snipping tool!

Comment: Thanks - I'm so happy now! It finally works!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the full URL to the image, i.e. the one you can see when you open them in the browser, something like:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/hjemmet.jpg" />
```

Comment: The img tag has no closing slash.

Comment: @rob, I know the <img> tag is self closing, really a bad habit, but as far as I know is still valid?

Comment: It's allowed but the specification states that it has no affect on anything and browsers are to ignore it so putting it in is meaningless and serves no purpose.